# I have an error with vb and SQL Server

Tags: sql, vb.net

When I try to update my table I have an error

This is the code

```
Private Sub babonar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles babonar.Click
    Dim saldo As Decimal
    Dim abonar As Double = 0
    Dim cedula As String
    Dim abono As New ClaseAbono

    saldo = Convert.ToDecimal(ttsaldo.Text)
    abonar = Convert.ToDouble(ttabonar.Text)

    cedula = ttcecula.Text
    abono.Nombre = ttnombre.Text
    abono.Saldo = saldo
    abono.Cedula = cedula
    abono.Abonar = abonar

    abono.Abono()
End Sub
```

This is the code of the class

```
 Public Function Abono()
    Dim vcedula As String = ""
    Dim retur As Boolean
    Dim saldoo As Double = 0

    saldoo = xsaldo - xabonar

    Dim sql As String = "update Cliente set Abono = @Abonar, Saldo = @saldoo  where Cedula = @Cedula"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(sCon)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        Try
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Abono", xabonar)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Saldo", saldoo)

            conn.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Console.WriteLine("Error actualizando datos ")
        End Try
    End Using

    Return retur
End Function
```

and this is the error

> Primera excepción del tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll

English

> First exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: On what line of your code does that exception get thrown?

Comment: The SqlException has detailed error message that well tell you what the issue is.   What is the message of the exception?

Comment: don't say that line have error :S only show the message error

Comment: In your Catch block, if you do Console.WriteLine(ex) what does it show?  That should give you the full text of the exception as well as the stack trace which will contain the line number of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not very useful. However, there are a couple of potential problems. The sql command parameters need the `@` symbol. Also, you need to add the `cedula` parameter.

In other words, this code:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Abono", xabonar)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Saldo", saldoo)
```

Should be changed to:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Abono", xabonar)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saldo", saldoo)
' you will need to substitute your correct variable for the `cedula` variable here '
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cedula", cedula)
```

Comment: @Gatiko: ***most likely***, the exception you're getting contains `.InnerException` details. You need to look at those inner exceptions (which can be nested several levels deep) for more useful details